# Seemingly valid C++ code not compilable with g++ in Mac

Tags: c++, macos, struct, g++, heap-memory

I am currently working on a C++ course from Udemy. The code presented there works fine, but it is not compilable for me:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Film {
    const int jahr;
    const char *titel;
    const char *regisseur;
};

int main() {

    Film star_wars_7{2015, "Star Wars the Force Awakens", "J. J. Abrams"};
    std::cout << star_wars_7.jahr << std::endl;
    std::cout << star_wars_7.titel << std::endl;
    std::cout << star_wars_7.regisseur << std::endl;

    Film star_wars_8{2017, "Star Wars the Last Jedi", "Rian Johnson"};
    std::cout << star_wars_8.jahr << std::endl;
    std::cout << star_wars_8.titel << std::endl;
    std::cout << star_wars_8.regisseur << std::endl;

    Film star_wars_9{2019, "Star Wars the Rise of Skywalker", "J. J. Abrams"};
    std::cout << star_wars_9.jahr << std::endl;
    std::cout << star_wars_9.titel << std::endl;
    std::cout << star_wars_9.regisseur << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Does anyone know, why I cannot compile it?

Another thing that doesn't work for me is the initialization of a variable on the heap. In the course, it is done as follows:

```
int *p_zahl = new int {4};
```

Instead, I have to use:

```
int *p_zahl = new int (4);
```

Is this a problem of the compiler?

Comment: Maybe provide `-std=c++17` so you're using C++17?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if I provide your flag it works. Is there a way to set this flag is standard behavior, so that I don't always have to type it?

Comment: I compiled your code with g++ in windows and it's ok.

Comment: You can use `make` and use the environment. The make command calls the compiler and passes CXX_FLAGS. `export CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++17` then you can `make struktor`

Comment: Please post the output as text.  You picture is difficult to read.

Comment: It's unclear why the code uses `const int jahr` instead of just `int jahr`, then you wouldn't need for C++17 in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys. The problem was, that I had to set the flag `-std=c++17`. To use this as default behavior, I added an alias to my `.bashrc`:

```
alias g++='g++ -std=c++17'
```